# MySql GRANT error: 'Select' is not valid at this position

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-grant

I'm trying to assign rights to newly created user sing MySQL Workbench but it gives me error as below (User creation was successful)

[image]

Version : 8.0.17
OS: MacOS Mojave

PS: `GRANT all ON`my_schema`.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';` was successful

Comment: You are missing a `,` between "update" and "delete".

Comment: That was really stupid thing from me. thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a comma between update and delete

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON my_schema.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

works also